# django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-orm

После выполнения команды `python manage.py makemigrations` в папке migrations   создается файл с новой миграцией, однако при выполнении какой либо миграции django выдает ошибку **django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: CPU has no field named 'series'**? Я даже пробовал полностью закомментировать файл models.py и admin.py, потом выполнил команду `python manage.py makemigrations`и в консоли появилось следующее:

```
(djangoprojects) E:\djangoprojects\djangoshop>python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'computerapp':
  computerapp\migrations\0038_auto_20190224_1506.py
    - Alter unique_together for cpu (0 constraint(s))
    - Remove field category from cpu
    - Remove field core from cpu
    - Remove field series from cpu
    - Remove field socket from cpu
    - Remove field product from gallery
    - Delete model Category
    - Delete model Core
    - Delete model CPU
    - Delete model Gallery
    - Delete model Series
    - Delete model Socket
```

в папке migrations появился файл с миграцией. Но после команды `python manage.py migrate` всё равно появляется та же ошибка. Я также попробовал выполнить `python manage.py migrate <app_name> <migration_name>`, но все равно получается тот же результат. Как избавиться от данной проблемы?
Полное содержание ошибки:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, computerapp, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying computerapp.0032_auto_20190224_1159... OK
  Applying computerapp.0033_auto_20190224_1240...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\djangoprojects\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 564, in get_field
    return self.fields_map[field_name]
KeyError: 'series'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "E:\djangoprojects\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "E:\djangoprojects\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "E:\djangoprojects\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "E:\djangoprojects\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "E:\djangoprojects\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\djangoprojects\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 203, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "E:\djangoprojects\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "E:\djangoprojects\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "E:\djangoprojects\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "E:\djangoprojects\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "E:\djangoprojects\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 150, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.remove_field(from_model, from_model._meta.get_field(self.name))
  File "E:\djangoprojects\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 327, in remove_field
    self._remake_table(model, delete_field=field)
  File "E:\djangoprojects\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 266, in _remake_table
    self.create_model(temp_model)
  File "E:\djangoprojects\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 300, in create_model
    columns = [model._meta.get_field(field).column for field in fields]
  File "E:\djangoprojects\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 300, in <listcomp>
    columns = [model._meta.get_field(field).column for field in fields]
  File "E:\djangoprojects\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 566, in get_field
    raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: CPU has no field named 'series'
```

Comment: Вам же django пишет, что модель CPU не имеет поля series. Ровно как и такой модели у вас нет. Но есть где-то ссылка или попытка вызвать "CPU.series"

Comment: @Ins так я полностью закомментировал файлы models.py и admin.py, и я больше нигде кроме как в этих файлах не ссылался на  "CPU.series".

Comment: @Ins добавил полный код ошибки в описание

Comment: В базе хранится информация о применённых миграциях. В файлах миграций хранятся последовательности изменений схемы. Судя по симптомам у вас эта последовательность нарушена.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После комментария @andreymal меня начало терзать чувство неудовлетворенности, поэтому я заново спровоцировал данную ошибку. Заглянул в только, что созданный файл миграции, и увидел следующее:

```
# Generated by Django 2.1.5 on 2019-02-24 17:24

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('computerapp', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='series',
            name='cpu',
            field=models.ForeignKey(default=1, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='computerapp.CPU'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='cpu',
            name='series',
        ),
        migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
            name='cpu',
            unique_together={('model', 'type_delievery')},
        ),
    ]
```

Как заметил, @Ins:

> django пишет, что модель CPU не имеет поля series.

Однако в файле с миграцией сгенерирован следующий код:

```
 migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='cpu',
            name='series',
        ),
```

В данном коде якобы удаляется поле series из модели CPU, но как оно удалится, если django мне с пеной у рта говорит, что его нет? В итоге я решил закоментить данный участок кода и вуаля всё работает. Огромное спасибо @andreymal и @Ins вы мне очень помогли.

Answer (score 0):

Увы, но проблема решилась только путем удаления всех файлов, кроме файла *init*.py из папки migrations, а также удаления файла db.sqlite3. После всего этого, заново выполнил команды `python manage.py makemigrations` и `python manage.py migrate` и только потом заново создал модели, точнее сказать раскоментировал файлы: models.py и admin.py и все заработоло, новые миграции снова начали применяться.

Comment: Ну вы просто обошли проблему, а не решили её

Comment: @andreymal к сожалению ничего кроме этого в голову не пришло